# 8085 program to add two 8-bit numbers in 8085 simulator

Tags: 8085, cpu-architecture

I am trying to add two 8 bit number and wrote the following code:

```
MVI D 08h
MVI B 03h
MVI C 00h
MOV A D
LOOP: CMP B
JC DOWN
INR A
SUB B
JNZ LOOP

DOWN: HLT
```

But I got incorrect output.

Comment: Why not simply use the 'Add' instruction? Example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/assembly-language-program-8085-microprocessor-add-two-8-bit-numbers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well assuming my assumption is correct that you are storing answer in `C`,

then just do a small change on **7th line**:

```
MVI D 08h
MVI B 03h
MVI C 00h
MOV A D
LOOP: CMP B
JC DOWN
INR C
SUB B
JNZ LOOP

DOWN: HLT
```

It should work now.